# Detect that a PHP link causes a file download in c#

Tags: c#, php, file, download, detect

I can't seem to find a working answer to my problem and I wonder if someone out there can help. Basically I have a link on my website which causes a zip file to be downloaded:

```
http://***.com/download.php?id=1
```

If you activate this link on the web page it will bring up a save as dialog and lets you save the file with default name `ThisIsMyZipFile.zip`

My problem is that under c# If I use `new Uri("http://***.com/download.pgp?id=1").IsFile` it returns `false` so I cannot seem to detect that this is a file without performing a `webclient DownloadString` and seeing if the first two bytes are `PK`.

Also even if manually download as a string detect the `PK` header and save the file I cannot find out what my web site wants to use as the default filename being `ThisIsMyZipFile.zip` in this example as I want to use the same filename.

Does anyone know a nice way of solving these two problems please?

***UPDATE***

Thanks to Paul and his answer I created the following function which does exactly what I need:

```
/// <summary>
/// Returns the responded HTTP headers of the given URL and if the link refers to the file it returns extra information about it.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="Url">The address.</param>
/// <returns>
/// null if a WebException is thrown
/// otherwise:
/// List of headers:
///     Keep-Alive          - Timeout value (i.e. timeout=2, max=100)
///     Connection          - The type of connection (i.e. Keep-Alive)
///     Transfer-Encoding   - The type of encoding used for the transfer (i.e. chunked)
///     Content-Type        - The type of Content that will be transferred (i.e. application/zip)
///     Date                - The servers date and time
///     Server              - The server that is handling the request (i.e. Apache)
///     AbsoluteUri         - The full Uri of the resulting link that will be followed.
/// The following key will be present if the link refers to a file
///     Filename            - The filename (not path) of the file that will be downloaded if the link if followed.
/// </returns>
public Dictionary<string, string> GetHTTPResponseHeaders(string Url)
{
    WebRequest WebRequestObject = HttpWebRequest.Create(Url);
    WebResponse ResponseObject = null;
    try
    {
        ResponseObject = WebRequestObject.GetResponse();
    }
    catch(WebException ex)
    {
        return null;
    }
    // Add the header inforamtion to the resulting list
    Dictionary<string, string> HeaderList = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    foreach (string HeaderKey in ResponseObject.Headers)
        HeaderList.Add(HeaderKey, ResponseObject.Headers[HeaderKey]);

    // Add the resolved Uri to the resulting list
    HeaderList.Add("AbsoluteUri", ResponseObject.ResponseUri.AbsoluteUri);

    // If this is a zip file then add the download filename specified by the server to the resulting list
    if (ResponseObject.ContentType.ToLower() == "application/zip")
    {
        HeaderList.Add("Filename", ResponseObject.ResponseUri.Segments[ResponseObject.ResponseUri.Segments.Length-1]);
    }

    // We are now finished with our response object
    ResponseObject.Close();

    // Return the resulting list
    return HeaderList;
}
```

Comment: MSDN says that IsFile is only true if it matches UriSchemeFile. See http://bit.ly/TB6HZi and http://bit.ly/W6A2pA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Uri.IsFile` performs a static check upon the URI, i.e. it sees whether the 'scheme' part (the first bit including the colon) is `file:`. It does not look at the actual content returned by requesting the resource that resides at the URI. (In fact, because it does not actually attempt to contact the server at all, the URI could actually point to a missing resource and yet `IsFile` would still work.)

If you wish to see if the content of the resource is of a particular type then you will have to either:

1. Retrieve the HTTP header for the resource (if it is an HTTP or HTTPs resource: that is, if the 'scheme' is `http` or `https`).
2. Retrieve (at least part of) the resource and examine it.

You are currently doing 2, but for an HTTP resource (with an HTTP URL) then it would be cleaner and cheaper to do 1. You can do this by performing an HTTP `HEAD` request (as opposed to `GET` or `POST`, &c.). This will return the HTTP headers without returning the resource itself. The code would look something like:

```
var request = WebRequest.Create("http://somewhere.overtherainbow.com/?a=b");
request.Method = "HEAD";
WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
//TODO check status code
string contentType = response.ContentType;
response.Close();
```

The content type will give you some indication of the file type, but many binary files will just be returned as an octet stream, so you may still need to retrieve and examine the magic bytes of the resource itself if you wish to differentiate between different binary file types. (The content type should be sufficient for you to differentiate between a binary file and a web page though.)

So, a full solution may be:

1. Send a `GET` request for the resource.
2. Check the response status to make sure there was no error.
3. Check the content type header to see if we have a binary octet stream.
4. Read two bytes from the response stream to see if it the file starts 'PK'.

Answer (score 1):

You absolutely cannot detect that a given URL would cause a file to be downloaded without actually sending an HTTP request to this url.

Now to the second problem. You could send an HTTP request to download the file and then inspect the Content-Disposition header which will contain the filename:

```
using (var client = new WebClient())
{
    using (var stream = client.OpenRead("http://*.com/download.php?id=1"))
    {
        var disposition = client.ResponseHeaders["Content-Disposition"];
        if (disposition != null)
        {
            var cd = new ContentDisposition(disposition);
            if (!cd.Inline && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(cd.FileName))
            {
                using (var outputStream = File.OpenWrite(cd.FileName))
                {
                    stream.CopyTo(outputStream);
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // The web server didn't send a Content-Disposition response header
            // so we have absolutely no means of determining the filename
            // you will have to use some default value here if you want to store it
        }
    }
}
```